# entityQuery where a translation with a different value returns incorrect nodes

Tags: 8, entities, database, i18n-l10n

The title seems a bit odd, I know, but I couldn't find any issues similar to this and that's the best I could come up with.  We are running into an odd instance of entityQuery returning nodes that shouldn't be returned.

We have a site with 3 languages installed, EN, PT-BR and ES.  I have an entityQuery where I'm trying to select nodes with conditions for two entity reference fields (genre and platform, both custom vocabularies, being queried on the custom field 'field_shortname'), in one of the 3 languages.  There are currently 3 nodes.  The first 2 nodes reference 'arcade' and 'ps4' in all languages.  The third node references 'arcade' and 'switch' in EN and PT-BR, but 'arcade' and 'ps4' in ES.  I'm trying to query for nodes in EN with reference 'arcade' and 'ps4' - Here's the entityQuery code:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');    
$query->condition('type', 'game');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('langcode', 'en', '=');
$query->condition(
  $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_genre.entity.field_shortname', 'arcade')
);
$query->condition(
  $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_platform.entity.field_shortname', 'ps4')
);
$query->execute();
```

I expect the query to return the 2 nodes that reference 'arcade' and 'ps4' in EN.  Instead, all 3 are being returned - I'm assuming since the 3rd node references 'ps4' in one of the translations.  I've tried adding the langcode into the conditions, which fixes the EN query but breaks the queries when I try the other languages - they return nothing instead:

```
$query->condition(
  $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_genre.entity.field_shortname', 'arcade', '=', 'es')
);
$query->condition(
  $query->andConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_platform.entity.field_shortname', 'ps4', '=', 'es')
);
```

Anybody have any ideas?  Seems like it should be a pretty straightforward query, but I just can't seem to get anything to return the correct results.  This is on Drupal 8.3.7.  Thanks in advance!